# Prove that $f(ab) = f(a) + f(b)$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, logarithms

**Question :** Assume only that $f: (0,\infty)\to{\mathbb{R}}$ is differentiable and that $f'(x) = 1/x$, and $f(1)=0$. Prove that for all $a,b \in(0,\infty)$, $f(ab)=f(a)+f(b)$. [Hint: Let $g(x)=f(ax)$]

**My solution :** We know that
$$f(x) = \int f'(x)dx = \int\frac{1}{x}dx = \ln(x) + C$$

Also, we are given that $f(1)=0$, so $f(1)=\ln(1)+C=0$, which gives us $C=0$. Therefore, $f(x)= \ln(x)$.

Now, by the laws of logarithm, we have $\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+ \ln(b)$ for all $a,b\in(0,\infty)$. Hence, $f (ab) = f(a) + f(b)$.

Is this the right approach? I am not really sure how to use the hint of letting $g(x) = f(ax)$.

Comment: Is it the case that $ln$ is not defined in your book before this exercise?

Comment: This is a question from a problem set for my Core Mathematics class. We don't really have a textbook, so I think it's okay to use _ln_ ?

Comment: @Shahab Minor nitpick: I think it is recommended to  use \ln, not ln, to render as $\ln (n)$, not $ln n$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need no integral.

Consider, as the hint tells you, $g(x)=f(ax)$ and compute its derivative:
$$
g'(x)=af'(ax)=a\frac{1}{ax}=\frac{1}{x}
$$
Therefore there exists $k$ such that, for every $x$,
$$
g(x)=k+f(x)
$$
(because differentiable functions defined over an interval that have the same derivative differ by a constant, a well known consequence of the mean value theorem).

Now compute at $x=1$: $g(1)=k+f(1)$, that means $f(a)=k$. Now the above identity, for $x=b$, reads
$$
f(ab)=f(a)+f(b)
$$

Comment: You should mention that your "there exists $k$" statement is due to Rolle's theorem or something. =)

Answer (score 6):

Usually such a theorem is used to **prove** the properties of the natural logarithm which is defined as $\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}\ dt$. In that case your proof is invalid simply because $\ln$ is not defined yet!

To prove the theorem directly, consider $\int_1^{ab} \frac{1}{t}\ dt = \int_1^a \frac{1}{t}\ dt + \int_a^{ab} \frac{1}{t}\ dt$ and try to prove that $\int_a^{ab} \frac{1}{t}\ dt = \int_1^b \frac{1}{t}\ dt$.

Note that while *egreg*'s answer does not need integration, it does not prove the existence of the function with the specified properties. This isn't necessary since the question already gave such a function, but one rigorous way of defining $\ln$ is precisely via the integral, so in fact this answer proves more than required, at the expense of using stronger mathematical machinery.

Comment: But if your problem is a high-school problem, then I think your solution is fine, since usually high-school mathematics **assumes** the properties of $\ln$ without proof.

Comment: The high school books that I use defines $\ln$ as the inverse of $f(x) = e^x$, and prove $\ln(ab) = \ln(a) + \ln(b)$ by raising each side to the power of $e$, see that in both cases we get $ab$, and appealing to injectivity of the exponential function. So the properties are not assumed without proof, although it does go over the heads of most of the students.

Comment: And if you don't mind geometric arguments, the equality you need to prove is obvious by noting that if you stretch the graph of $y = \frac{1}{x}$ by a factor of $a$ in the $x$-coordinate and then squash it by a factor of $a$ in the $y$-coordinate, the area under the graph from $1$ to $b$ becomes the area under the graph from $a$ to $ab$, but stretching and squashing by the same factor preserves the area!

Comment: @Arthur: The problem with that is that the properties of $\exp$ are as difficult to prove as the properties of $\ln$, so the lack of justification is still there.

Comment: If you don't like geometric arguments, use the substitution $t = au$.

Comment: At high school level, you can prove the rules for natural powers, then once you define negative powers, you can show that the rules still hold (in fact, they should be made aware that negative powers are defined that way _exactly_ because the rules still hold). Same with rational powers. It is certainly a leap of faith to assume that it holds for real powers from there, but intuitively, it certainly should.

Comment: @Arthur: That is certainly one way to do it, which is made rigorous in many undergraduate introductory analysis courses. I think that's fine as long as students are really clear that it **is indeed** an assumption about real exponentiation (whether called leap of faith or otherwise). =)

Answer (score 0):

Shortly,

$$f'(ax)-f'(x)=\frac a{ax}-\frac1x=0.$$

By differentiability $f(ax)-f(x)$ is a constant, so that with $x=b$ and $x=1$

$$f(ab)-f(b)=f(a)-f(1)=f(a).$$

Comment: What difference with my answer?

Comment: @egreg: it's shorter, as said in the short introduction.

Comment: I don't see it being shorter, unless you count the number of words.

Comment: @egreg: you get it.